# How to concatenate strings with quotes to another string with multiple quotes on JS

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I'm trying to write JS code and I have to concatenate multiple strings with variables in them to form a giant string.

```
var another_class = 'datatables-more';
var color = "#e07c8a";
var NYC = "New York City";
var LA = "Los Angeles";
var url = "/my/app/url2";
var some_url = "/my/app/url";
var row_count = row['available_count'];

data = '<td><div class="' + another_class + 'item-count-div" style="background-color:' + color + '"' + ' data-url="' + url + '"' + ' data-toggle="popover" data-content="" + row_count + '</div></td>';
```

Now, for the `data-content` attribute, I want it's value to be:

```
data-content = "<a href="some_url">NYC</a> <a href="some_url">LA</a>"
```

`some_url`, `NYC`, `LA` are all variables. How can I achieve this result? I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

I have tried to do this:

```
data-content="<a href="'+some_url+'">'+NYC+'</a>"'
```

This didn't work and gives me weird `ahref` tag.

Comment: Actually the issue is, you are not allowed to use '-' in JS variable names. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using newer version, you can refer to the previous answer, otherwise you can do something like:

Update: Following code works perfectly. It was html causing issue.

```
var another_class = 'datatables-more';
var color = "#e07c8a";
var NYC = "New York City";
var LA = "Los Angeles";
var url = "/my/app/url2";
var some_url = "/my/app/url";
var row_count = row['available_count'];

var dataContent = '<a href=\''+some_url+'\'>'+NYC+'</a> <a href=\''+some_url+'\'>'+LA+'</a>';

var data = '<td> <div class="' + another_class + ' item-count-div" style="background-color:'+ color + ';" data-url="' + url + '" data-toggle="popover" data-content="'+dataContent+'" >' + row_count + '</div></td>';
```

Comment: Didn't work. Give me error: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

Comment: can you share your whole piece of code with these variables declared?

Comment: This doesn't give any error, but gives this end output html, which is wrong:
`data-content="<a href=" my="" app="" url"="" data-original-title="" title="">New York City <a href="/my/app/url">Los Angeles</a>"76</div>`

Comment: I think there is something missing here, are you concatenating this with your main 'data' string and how are you doing this? Can you share that with me.

Comment: Yes, correct, var data is the combination of all of these strings. It is one big giant string. I'm trying to create the `<td>` element. It is in my question how I'm doing this - declaring variables before and joining them one by one

Comment: what is row_count? and to which attribute you are trying to append it?

Comment: `row_count` is a variable and it will be `<div>` text like this `<td><div>row_count</div></td>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212882/discussion-between-hamza-arshad-and-di437).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using newer versions of JS you could use a string template literal, like this:

```
const data = `<a href="${var1}">${var2}</a>`
```

Another approach is to use an array and the join function, like this:

```
const parts = ['<a href="', var1, '">", var2, '</a>'];
const data = parts.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '<td> <div class="' + another_class + 'item-count-div" style="background-color:' 
+ color + ';"' + ' data-url="'+url+'" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<a 
  href="'+url+'">NYC</a>  <a href="'+url+'">LA</a>" >' + row_count + '</div></td>';
```